# Is it possible to have a Google Analytics tracking event on Tumblr's Follow button?

Tags: google-analytics, dom-events, tumblr

Is there a way to hack a Tumblr theme to put a Google Analytics `_trackEventI()` function on the Tumblr Follow button? This would allow users to analyze where people are coming from when they click follow, what pages they clicked follow on, demographics of people who followed, etc.

Comment: Why would you? You can see the amount of followers in the Tumblr Dashboard - unless you want to track something else that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you control the code that displays it, or if the code is iframed onto your site but the iframe content is hosted on your domain then yes, it is possible.  But if it is iframed onto your page and the iframed content is not on your domain then no, you cannot add tracking to it.